# Confused by an example of generalization of a point

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. We say that a point $P\in\operatorname{Spec}A$ is a generalization of a point $Q\in\operatorname{Spec}A$ if $Q\in\overline{\{P\}}$. So let $P=[(y-x^2)]$ and $Q=[(x-2,y-4)]$. The claim is that $P$ is a generalization of $Q$, but I'm having trouble seeing this.

I know that $(y-x^2)\in (x-2,y-4)$, which is equivalent to the ideal $(y-x^2)$ vanishing at the closed point $(x-2,y-4)$ (which we can think of as $(2,4)$). But this doesn't help me see that $(x-2,y-4)\in\overline{(y-x^2)}$ (where the closure is with respect to the Zariski topology).

Now, certainly, $[(x-2,y-4)]$ is a closed point, but why is it in the intersection of all closed subsets containing $(y-x^2)$? Is there a better way to see this? How would one go about finding the closure of $(y-x^2)$?

Comment: Hint: what are the closed subsets of $\operatorname{Spec} R$? Write down the definition. (Your final paragraph also seems to have a typo - you'd want to be looking at the intersection of closed subsets, not closed points.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove that $(x - 2, y - 4)$ is in the closure of $\{ (y - x^2 ) \}$, you have to prove that every closed set that contains $(y - x^2 )$ also contains $(x - 2, y - 4)$.

By the definition of the Zariski topology, the closed sets in ${\rm Spec \ }A$ are sets of the form $V(I) = \{ \mathfrak p { \rm \ prime \ } \subset A : I \subseteq \mathfrak p \}$.

But if $I \subseteq A$ is any ideal such that $V(I)$ contains $(y - x^2)$, then $I \subseteq (y - x^2) \subset (x - 2, y - 4)$ too, hence $V(I)$ contains $(x - 2, y - 4)$. Thus $(x - 2, y - 4)$ is in the closure of $\{ (y - x^2 ) \}$.

[By the way, I used the fact that $(y - x^2 ) \subset (x - 2, y - 4)$.]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a convenient way to compute $\overline{[(y-x^2)]}$ in full?

Comment: @ponchan The closure is simply going to be $V((y - x^2))$, since this is the smallest closed set that contains $(y - x^2)$. And $V((y - x^2))$ contains $(y - x^2)$ plus all of the maximal ideals that represent points on this parabola.

Comment: How to know $V((y-x^2))$ is the smallest such ideal?

Comment: Well, if $V(I)$ is some other closed set that contains $(y - x^2)$ and $\mathfrak p$ is some prime ideal in $V((y - x^2))$, then $I \subseteq (y - x^2) \subseteq \mathfrak p$. Thus $V((y - x^2)) \subseteq V(I)$.